# Design the data base schema

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a coupon table in Postgres which has 50+ columns.

DB schema is like:

- id : String ,
- code : String ,
- restrict_to_user : text[] // an array store the profile id of user for which the coupon is valid ,
- restrict_to_hotel : text[] // an array of hotel for which the coupon is valid
  and many more entries .

Currently field restrict_to_user store an array of userId but when the restrict_to_user field gets large in that case the query get slow.

How to store the restrict_to_user field in DB . Also in future more type of restriction will come . How to handle them aslo ?

Answer (score 0):

From a data consistency stand point, you may want to normalize your schema rather than list users, hotels, etc in arrays. For example have a join table between your `coupons` and `users` tables that keeps track of users that are restricted to a particular coupon. You can add a unique constraint on the combination of coupon and user foreign keys to avoid recording duplicates. With the array approach, you're prone to having duplicates so you'll want to process your array either in your query (e.g. `unnest()` followed by a `group by`) or in your application code.

At large scale, there are also potential performance concerns with arrays of variable length types. That's if you do stick to `text[]` which I suspect should be `integer[]`. See https://heapanalytics.com/blog/engineering/dont-iterate-over-a-postgres-array-with-a-loop

Comment: Thanks for the update..but my use case is having many to many mappings between coupon and user...So for example a coupon 'x' is associated with millions of users in that case ..I will create a table that has millions of row Right?
Also how to handle dynamic restriction at runtime that will be added in future..For that should i create a separate table

Comment: Correct, you'd create a join table between your `coupons` and `users` tables, e.g. `coupon_restricted_users`, each row in that table pointing back to the `coupons` and `users` tables through foreign keys.